# App crashes when running getBondedDevices() function from flutter_bluetooth_serial dependency

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem running the `getBondedDevices()` function. Every time I run this function the app crashes.
This is part of my code:

```
Future<void> bluetoothConnectionState() async {
    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];

    // To get the list of paired devices
    try {
      devices = await bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Error");
    }
    setState(() {
      if(devices != null){
        _devicesList = devices;
      }
    });
}

Future<bool> booltest() async{
    if(flag){
      await bluetoothConnectionState(); // *TODO ver si funciona
    }
    return true;
}

// flag is true when bluetooth is available

FutureBuilder(
        future: booltest(),
        builder: (context, future){
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

Debug Console:

```
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(77)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000564d  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007fcfeede50
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000008000000000
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  b4406790ee6b6562  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 fffffff0fffffbdf  x13 0000000000000003  x14 0000000000000001  x15 0000000000000010
    x16 0000007bcea0b8c0  x17 0000007bce9e7a50  x18 0000007bd13c2000  x19 000000000000564d
    x20 000000000000564d  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007bd027a398  x23 0000007ad1aa8030
x24 0000000000000033  x25 0000000000000050  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000046
    x28 0000000000000001  x29 0000007fcfeedef0
    sp  0000007fcfeede30  lr  0000007bce9990c4  pc  0000007bce9990f0
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000830f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160) (BuildId: 1eb18e444251dc07dff5ebd93fce105c)
      .
      .
      .
      .
      #50 pc 000000000007e898  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: 1eb18e444251dc07dff5ebd93fce105c)

Lost connection to device.
```

The app only crashes when runs `getBondedDevices()` function, when I comment this function it doesn't crash.

I hope you can help me!! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding this to `android/gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```